# loading images from array into array of Div's using for-loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got an array of images:

```
var array-1 = new Array(map+"mach-1.jpg",map+"bras-1.jpg",map+"card-1.jpg",map+"rham-1.jpg",map+"icar-1.jpg");
```

and there's an array of div's with the id_0 to id_4.

I want to load the div with the appropriate array-1 item.
How can I do this?

Comment: What's inside the map variable and what does your div array look like?

Comment: A hyphen is invalid in a variable name, it's interpreted as a minus sign

Comment: Three step : 

1. Select the parent div
2. Iterate the children which match your requirement
3. Set the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to rename your array without the dash, but if you do you should be able to use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to populate your `div`s.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var array_1 = ["http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/1", "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/2", "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/3", "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/4", "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/5"];
  array_1.forEach(function(value,index) {
    $('#id_' + index).html('<img src="' + value + '" />');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id_0"></div>
<div id="id_1"></div>
<div id="id_2"></div>
<div id="id_3"></div>
<div id="id_4"></div>
```